# Unable to re-request a check run using the GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api, octokit

So I list all check runs from a specific ref using, and select the first one, then ask for a re-run (the check run failed):

```
const result = await octokit.checks.listForRef({
    owner: organization.providerLogin,
    repo: repository.name,
    ref: pullRequest.ref,
  });
const checkRun = result.data.check_runs[0]
await octokit.checks.rerequestRun({
    owner: organization.providerLogin,
    repo: repository.name,
    check_run_id: checkRun.id,
  });
```

But I receive this error `Invalid check_run_id '16889946523'`, so I'm looking for some help now, thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are listing checks for the same org/repo you are re-questing a run? I have doubts because It's not so obvious from the code snippet above.

Comment: You're right to ask the question, I merged different files to simplify the code snippet. But I check that the repository and organizatin are the same, so the error is not coming from these variables. I'll edit the code snippet